# Python - unavailable username

Tags: python, while-loop, boolean

I am trying to create a small program that registers a user to a text file. It asks the user to create a username and it checks if the chosen username already exists in that text file. If so I need the user to be in loop until they enter a different username. The file contains usernames and passwords for each individual separated by ", " eg. (Sanele, afkojs). Each user is stored in a separate line. My code is not keeping the user in this loop it goes through

```
cont_ = False 

while not cont_ :

    new_username = input(" Create a Username: ")

    unavail_usernames = file_opener("user_info") *#function that opens the text file*

    for names in unavail_usernames:

        user_info_list = names.split(", ") *#Every user is stored in a separate line* 

        if new_username != user_info_list[0]:

            cont_ = True

    if not cont_:

        print("username unavailable, enter a different username")

    unavail_usernames.seek(0)
```

Comment: Reading the file again for each iteration is very inefficient. Just read it into memory once, *then* loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
l=['a,b,c','d,e,f','g,h,i']
inp = input()
while inp in list(map(lambda x:x.split(',')[0],l)):
  print("username unavailable, enter a different username")
  inp=input()


print('Username is available')
```

Comment: what is that  x:x stand for? I am new to programming, already put it as it is but it says object not callable

Comment: It is a `lambda` function, it is used to apply a certain operation on an iterable, in this case on each element `x` on the list, I split it and get the first element and so on

Comment: well it says object not callable

Comment: Which object? Replace `l` with `unavail_usernames` and `inp` with `new_usrname`

Comment: i did exactly that and it gave me that error

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\sanel\Downloads\reg_user.py", line 20, in <module>
    while new_username in unavail_names(map(lambda x:x.split(", ")[0],unavail_names)):
TypeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object is not callable

Comment: The problem is in `unavail_usernames`, it should be a `list`,

Comment: owwwwww the was a typo, i had changed list to unavail_name. thank you so much it works now. I have no idea how maps,lambda works

Comment: Don't forget to upvote my answer and mark it as correct ;)

Answer (score 0):

This code

```
for names in unavail_usernames:
    user_info_list = names.split(", ") *#Every user is stored in a separate line* 

    if new_username != user_info_list[0]:

        cont_ = True
```

set `cont_` to `True` as soon as different name is found. You are checking: *does file hold any username different than given?* whilst you should: *does all username in file are different from given?*